# Which is better way to maintain error query log in php (In text file OR In database)?

Tags: php

I am building some system in which most of the source code is executing as a "Cron Job".I need to track/maintain error logs which shows me that where my code stucks.
So could you please guide me that, whether maintaining such a runtime logs in text file at some location OR maintain it in database.
Which is feasible and secured way to do so ?

Comment: I've changed the tags as this question is not framework specific. Don't throw random tags into your questions that are not related.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to maintian it in a file rather than at DB.Because if you maintian it in DB then it may give extra load on your DB.And access these record also will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I like apache log4php. Mainly because I have a lot of Java experience and it's similar to log4j.

log4php will allow you create what they call appenders. Appenders are responsible for delivering LogEvents to their destination. There are standard appenders to log to a DB, or file, or quite a few other places. You can even write your own.

You can even have different log level log to different appender (warning and errors go to the db and debug goes to a file) Or, log to multiple appenders at the same time. It's very configurable. When logging to a file, it will also roll over your files when they get to a certain size.

I prefer logging critical log data to a file. A DB can go down and you won't be able to see that it did in your logs.

The trick with logging to the filesystem is to put the logs in a secure folder *outside* of your web document root (public_html or whatever that may be on your system.) It's a pretty standard way of doing it. Although you can get creative and even have an appender that emails you critical errors.

http://logging.apache.org/log4php/quickstart.html